# Automatically update user_id and date fields at django into database

Tags: django, database, model, userid, calc

I'm new to Python and Django and there are some things I would like to achieve in models.py:
After a user submits a form I would like to safe both the current date and the current user_id of the user into the database.

I know django offers to use @property decorators for those, but the problem with that is that I would like to make SQL queries using user_id and that doesn't work with decorators.

Another related question is how to establish calc fields like an automatic calculation of two values in the form before submitting.

Comment: Hello, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide us minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Try making a model for the submission of the form. And give the model a foreign key which is connected to the user. Then add a DateField and prove the default value as datetime.now() from the datetime module which is probably already installed on your device.

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py I added this line: 'crum.CurrentRequestUserMiddleware',

In models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import crum


class PlantSpecies(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        userid = crum.get_current_user()
        self.userid = userid.id
        super(PlantSpecies, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    userid = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, default=crum.get_current_user())
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    common_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.species
```